# Homogeneous function - is it?

Tags: functions, homogeneous-equation

Alpha Chiang's book - Fundamental Methods of Mathematical Economics presents a question:

Is this homogeneous? If so, of what degree?

1. f(x,y) = ($x^2 - y^2)$$^0.^5$

My main issue is how to simplify it in order to multiply it by constant and find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is; to see this, substitute $tx, ty$ in for $x, y$ to get
$$f(tx,ty) = \sqrt{(tx)^2 - (ty)^2} = \sqrt{t^2x^2 - t^2y^2} = \sqrt{t^2(x^2 - y^2)} = t\sqrt{x^2-y^2} = t\cdot f(x,y). $$
Thus by definition $f$ is homogenous of degree $1$ since $t^1$ could be pulled out of the equation.

Comment: It's only *positively* homogeneous since this argument only works for $t\geq0$.

Comment: If there was an "A" at the start of the function, which is mentioned to be a constant, would the answer remain the same?

Comment: Check yourself; does adding a constant (say 2) to the front of the square root affect the argument in any way?

Comment: I suppose no. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, I'm thinking of two constants, one before x and one before y, and I suppose that wouldn't change our answer either?